# Polymer 2.0: Event listeners where is the ideal place to add it?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I've seen people adding the event listener on the "ready" function and others on "connectedCallback". My question is, what are the pros and cons of each place? On connected we are responsible to remove it; in ready, it will stay there, and I'm unsure if it is a problem.

**Should I do this:**

```
connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.addEventListener('click', this.myFunction.bind(this));
}

disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnetedCallback();
    this.removeEventListener('click', this.myFunction);
}
```

**Or this:**

```
ready() {
    super.ready();
    this.addEventListener('click', this.myFunction.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up until Polymer `1.x.whatever` , the `ready` callback in the life cycle of an element, was called, once

- the element registered its shadow DOM
- any `<content>`'s were distributed

and then, post `ready` , `attached` was fired

So, you could possibly have used `ready` as a one time callback after everything was indeed **ready**

With Polymer 2.0 onwards, there have been **contractual** changes to how callbacks are fired, and

- The `ready` callback no longer is guaranteed to execute after the new `<slots>` are distributed meaning, there is no surety that the ready itself will wait for content / light DOM distribution.
- `attached` is now the new `connectedCallback` and is essentially useful for element level DOM manipulations such as setting attributes , appending children etc. This is a lifecycle change that happens after the slot nodes are distributed and the element itself is attached in the DOM hierarchy, but **not** necessarily after a paint.

SO, for any event that does **not** rely on any `::slotted` content, use the `ready` callback

for anything that requires a knowledge of all distributed content along with the shadow DOM, use the `connectedCallback`

However, when possible, use the `afterNextRender` method of the super class `Polymer` , within your element's callback to add event listeners

these are what I could possibly think of.

All this and much more, if it helps, [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#callback-contracts-have-changed)

I haven't yet read about us having to remove an event listener from a lifecycle callback, or anything as such.

If you are referring to cases where, the element itself may be connected and disconnected dynamically / or in the flow of things,

And, with that in mind, you are adding an event listener on a global / native element within your element's life cycle callbacks ,

like attaching an event listener on the `window` inside your `custom-element`'s `ready` or `connectedCallback` ,

Only in such cases, does polymer advise you to **remove** the event listener on `disconnect`

Comment: much more clear now, I'll also check the about afertNextRender

Comment: Yeah. I haven't used it myself, but must be to prevent renderblocks do check it out cheers!

Comment: @AdrianoSpadoni in most of the case, the best time to assign an event listener, the earlier the better. I usually go for the constructor and define my event listeners inside.